# Python __imul__() method

Tags: python

I created my own array class and implemented the **imul**() method, but when i call the *= operation on an instance, the instance itself became a NoneType object. Any idea why it worked that way ?

```
class CustomArray:
    def __init__(self):
        self.array = []

    def append(self, value):
        self.array.append(value)

    def __mul__(self, scaler):
        return [n*scaler for n in self.array]

    def __imul__(self, scaler):
        #print('*= operation is called.', [n*scaler for n in self.array])
        self.array = [n*scaler for n in self.array]

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.array.__str__()

customArray = CustomArray()
print(customArray.array)
#output:[]
customArray.append(5)
customArray.append(15)
customArray.append(25)
customArray.append(35)
customArray.append(45)
print(customArray)
#output:[5, 15, 25, 35, 45]
print(customArray*5)
#output:[25, 75, 125, 175, 225]
customArray *= 5
print(customArray)
#output:None
```

Comment: [These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying `self`) and **return the result** (which could be, but does not have to be, `self`).](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__imul__)

Comment: That and I would create an helper method to avoid duplicating the scaling code.

Answer (score 5):

Just because you printed a valid result, doesn't mean thats how the method will return the data.

It does modify the data, but since you have no return, the actual value will be None.

You can `return self`, and it will work

```
def __imul__(self, scaler):
    #print('*= operation is called.', [n*scaler for n in self.array])
   self.array = [n*scaler for n in self.array]
   return self
```

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much!